# Разделить 1 переменную на 2 переменных

Tags: регулярные-выражения, координаты, javascript

Имеется переменная с координатами для Яндекс карты. Пример значения "38.935194 47.209580". Необходимо записать 38.935194 в одну переменную , а 47.209580 в другую соответственно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[split()](http://javascript.ru/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

Метод строки split() вам поможет:

```
var coords = ("38.935194 47.209580").split(" ")
    ,lng = coords[0]
    ,lat = coords[1]
;
```